# Set Navigation Bar Item Colors in MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift3

I'm currently having some difficulty trying to set the Cancel and Send button colors when I navigate to MFMailComposeViewController in iOS 10 using swift 3. I've tried setting the tint of the MFMailComposeViewController's UINavigationController, Bar, and Items with no success. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: What my current MFMailComposeViewController looks like]

How I open MFMailComposeViewController:

```
/* Open mail for the user to send a help emaail with questions about the app */
    func sendEmail() {

        if MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {

            let mail = MFMailComposeViewController()
            mail.mailComposeDelegate = self
            mail.setToRecipients(["himom@gmail.com"])
            mail.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue

            present(mail, animated: true)

        }
    }

    /* Called when mail is dismissed */
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
        controller.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Try setting the tint of the compose controller's view itself.

Comment: @LeoNatan tried adding `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.blue` before the initialization of the mail object and it did not help.

Comment: No. Try `mail.view.tintColor = .blue`

Comment: Also no luck with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a navigation color for your entire app, i.e the tints of the buttons match throughout the app you can try this:

Inside the `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `AppDelegate`

```
// Custom color for navigation bar
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.whateverTintColorYouWant
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whateverTextColorYouWant]
```

If you would only like this for the MailViewController try this:

```
// Custom color for navigation bar
mail.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.aColorYouwant
mail.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.aColorYouWant]
```

Comment: I could set the background and title color from the AppDelegate. I was not able to set the button colors so I ended up changing the background and title colors to work with the while buttons so they became visible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is amazing how poorly designed are those APIs created by Apple. Every single thing is half cooked.

Comment: The `navigationBar` appearance changes in `AppDelegate` don't appear to work. It seems no matter what I do I can't get the `tintColor` of the `navigationBar` inside the `MFMailComposeViewController` to honor what I set it to. Have tried what's shown above, changing those same attributes directly on the compose controller itself, and also building an extension of the class and overriding `viewDidLoad`. Has anyone found a way to do this reliably?

Comment: Found the problem with mine. See this answer for details. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47503809/10162227

Answer (score 2):

The final answer for me was the first comment from here: [How to change color of MFMailComposeViewController texts and button images?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29771633/12035498)
Where you have to set

```
mail.view.tintColor = .green
```

Then my buttons appeared green.